# Need symbolic link functionality WITHOUT symbolic pathname

Tags: windows, windows-10, ntfs, symbolic-link, mklink

Running Windows 10 Pro.

I am trying to work around the 260 character MAX_PATH limitation native to the Win32 API.

I have created a series of backups, which we'll say are designed to back up "TRUNCATED" filenames.

For example, we'll reference a file with the full filename:

`D:/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/Folder5/Folder6/Folder7/Folder8/Folder9/file.txt`

To start, I have theoretically shortened this filename by means of moving the file into a hidden folder `Short_Name` closer to the root, such that the file would now LITERALLY exist as

`D:/Short_Name/Folder9/file.txt`

However, in order to keep my original file structure intact, such that I can re-use this tactic to perform the same path shortening elsewhere, but still use the same configuration files and software to perform file duplication and synchronization WITHIN the original folder(s)

( such as `D:/Folder1/.../Folder9/` )

I have included a symbolic link named "`Folder9`"

( achieved using `C:\Windows\system32>` `mklink` `/J` ( or `/D` ) `"D:/Folder1/.../Folder9/"` `"D:/Short_Name/Folder9/"` in the command prompt )

within

`D:/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/Folder5/Folder6/Folder7/Folder8/`

such that the link looks like

`D:/Folder1/.../Folder9/`

but points to `D:/Short_Name/Folder9/`.

NOW, obviously, I could instead have used a regular, run-of-the-mill

> Right-click > "Create Shortcut"

but the link target pathname of such a symbolic link would be absolute.

( i.e. A shortcut on `D:` pointing to `D:/Short_Name/Folder9/file.txt` would get copied to `C:` but the copied shortcut duplicate on `C:` would still point to `D:/Short_Name/Folder9/file.txt`. )

Symbolic links, on the other hand...

(i.e. the ones created via `C:\Windows\system32>` `mklink` `...` )

... copy relative links over no problem...

( i.e. `D:/Folder1/.../Folder9/` would be copied as `C:/Folder1/.../Folder9/` )

... and the link target would copy from

`D:/Short_Name/Folder9/`

to

`C:/Short_Name/Folder9/`

... **BUT** --

The problem HERE is that NOW the LITERAL filenames are STILL INTERPRETED as their longer, UN-TRUNCATED versions, which would NOT occur by using the

> Right-click > "Create Shortcut"

method.

As far as I can tell, when using `mklink` to create a symbolic link to a directory ( NOT a file - I do not know if it works differently for files ) , the LITERAL system filename of any file housed within a directory such as `D:/Short_Name/Folder9/` seems only ever to be the entirety of the `mklink` symbolic path, i.e., namely that of

`D:/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/Folder5/Folder6/Folder7/Folder8/Folder9/file.txt`

even if the ACTUAL location of the file is only

`D:/Short_Name/Folder9/file.txt`.

**QUESTION:**

> Is there ANY way of creating a symbolic link which will function as a standard folder, but which will ALSO maintain the RELATIVE, LITERAL, TRUNCATED version of a filename when copied to a new drive?

Please and thank you.

Comment: I don't really get what your problem is. But you might want to read [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx) which has specifics on how to work with paths that are longer. In addition the obvious and easy solution would be to shorten the paths or use software that is able to work with those paths. An example would be to not use Explorer but something like Total Commander. Furthermore there is a heavy difference between using `mklink` with the options `/J` and `/D`.

Comment: the 260 MAX_PATH limit is **not** related to NTFS. It's just the limit of the old Win32 API. Windows NT has support 32767-character path for a very long time, and [Windows 10 also support longer paths](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27694470/995714)

Comment: @Seth, the difference here is between shortening 1,000+ file names individually and just shortening the longer directory via a symbolic link.  Yes, /J and /D are different, but the ISSUE I'm having remains the same, regardless of whether it is a junction or a soft link.  I am aware of alternative file explorers.  But I want NATIVE Win32 API support because that is the environment in which most 3rd-party developers develop their applications; switching methods **I** use to browse files does not guarantee the 1,000+ files I have will remain viable for their respective applications.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Thank you for correcting me on the point of Win32; I have updated the original post, accordingly.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc With respect to the compatibility of Windows 10 as it relates to longer file names, while I am sure that I could disable the setting which currently disallows filenames greater than 260 characters, I am worried that doing so would cause application instability.  Is there a way to confirm one way or another how manipulating the MAX_PATH setting would affect the ability of certain applications to make use of the affected files?

Comment: there's no problem whatsoever, because only applications manifested to support long file name will have longer MAX_PATH, others are still limited to 260 characters if they don't use NT-style path https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/07/30/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10/ https://news.slashdot.org/story/16/05/31/0012222/microsoft-removes-260-character-path-length-limit-in-windows-10-redstone

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, it should be noted that some doubt has been raised about whether Windows *actually* checks the application manifest, despite what the documentation says.  I haven't attempted to verify this myself.

Comment: But by actually fixing your paths you probably would not have to shorten the names of a thousand files. Essentially, from what I understand, that is your approach anyway. It's just not clear where you're encountering a problem with it. As the initial link points out you could just use a different path and give it a shot. Usually if you're doing unusual things, like massively exceeding path lengths, you will need tools that support your case or fix your stuff to make it comply to the standard.

Comment: @Seth the solution I seek is for the directory structure to appear identical to one with many nested directories such as one which would create files with pathnames longer than 260 characters, as long as either a user is simply browsing the folders in Explorer, or if an application is trying to treat every shortcut/symlink/some third potential alternative as an actual folder, yet with the ACTUAL pathnames being less than that.  Shortcut = yes, but with absolute pathnames that don't copy, Symlink (mklink) = relative pathnames that do copy, but no shorter pathnames.